# Display Views exposed form item label inside selects (Instead of the default '- Any -')?

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-7, view

How to display form item label in Views exposed form instead of `'- Any -'`? To be more specific I use this code to replace select's default value text with custom text and want that custom text to be the label of that element:

```
function THEMENAME_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  //dpm($form);
  if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-FORMID') {
$form['ITEMNAME']['#options']['All'] = t('My custom translatable text');    
  }
}
```

This works for custom text. What I want is to display its label instead of `My custom translatable text` with the simple code like:

```
$form['ITEMNAME']['#options']['All'] = $form['ITEMNAME']['#name'];
```

but have no luck on such and similar codes to work. According fo $dpm($form) output `'#name', '#title'` elements seem not to exist at all.

The goal is to have similar functionality of https://drupal.org/project/compact_forms or https://drupal.org/project/In-Field-Labels without another Javascript library (prefer to use couple PHP lines, please no JS solutions)

Answer (score 2):

Your above code will work in case of select field but not for text field. If you need it to work for text fields you can try this

```
$form['ITEMNAME']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder' => array('My custom translatable text'));
```

or

```
$form['ITEMNAME']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder' =>$form['ITEMNAME']['#name']);
```

hope this helps you

Comment: Wow, forgotten about that attribute, problem is solved for text fields but I would like to have the solution for BOTH: selects and text fields. Selects seem not to have 'placeholder' attribute and the code I posted above does NOT work, I get '1' as an output for $form['ITEMNAME']['#name'];

Comment: for that you will need to have a if condition which will check the type first & then apply a solution for it. It cannot be done using a single solution

Comment: Seems problem is that #title attribute is not present in those selects. I do fully understand your logic - this part is clear